# What are the advantages of using Batch ackMode over Record in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, workflow, spring-kafka, camunda

I'm new to Kafka and designing a process flow using Kafka and Camunda to perform multiple short operations in a linear flow. I need to understand which is the best suited ackMode for my Listener - Batch or Record. Which is better for timeout scenarios? And which is better for error handling?

Answer (score 2):

When we poll the consumer, we get multiple records.

With RECORD mode, the offset is committed after each record is processed.

With BATCH mode, the offsets are all committed after all records in the batch are processed.

It's a trade off between I/O between the client/broker and the possibility of receiving duplicate deliveries after a system crash.